Covariant derivative for spin-2 field
I have mostly seen the concept of covariant derivative with regard to spin-1 fields. Is it possible to define the covariant derivative for spin-2 fields as well?

What are you referring to as the covariant derivative? In the context of gravity, the covariant derivative already applies to all tensor fields. Do you mean the covariant derivative used in gauge theory to couple matter fields to gauge fields?

Yes. For the spin-1 case one replaces $\partial_{\mu}$ with $D_{\mu}$. I was wondering if there is any such thing for spin-2.

Spin-two is  the same thing as a traceless, symmetric tensor field, so I imagine that the usual tensor covariant derivative would work.
